# Encode url in php

Tags: php, url

I have string url variable;

```
$url ="http://carkva-gazeta.org/римско-католическая-церковь/";
```

I need transform $url to:

```
"http://carkva-gazeta.org/%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bc%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d1%86%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%8c/"
```

I have tried: `rawurlencode($url);`
and `urlencode($url);`
But result is:

```
http%3A%2F%2Fcarkva-gazeta.org%2F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%86%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8C%2F
```

Comment: You are enconding even `http://carkva-gazeta.org/` so this is why you get that result, remove from the url before encoding, and add it after

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably that's the best solution:

```
$url ="http://carkva-gazeta.org/римско-католическая-церковь/";

$x = parse_url($url);

echo $x['scheme'].'://'.$x['host'].strtolower(str_replace('%2F','/',urlencode($x['path'])));
```

I've used also `strtolower` to make it lowercase as you wanted

Answer (score 2):

```
$url = "http://carkva-gazeta.org/";
$url .= urlencode("римско-католическая-церковь");

echo $url;
```

Like so?

Comment: I retrieve url value from another module, I know nothing about it, so I can not encode only some part of value.

Comment: You never mentioned that... How is one meant to know what you do not tell?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are getting your URL string automatically/dynamically and that it is not a fixed string that you can simply split while writing your code, you'll want something like this

```
$url = "http://carkva-gazeta.org/римско-католическая-церковь/";

// in case it is https, we don't want to hardcode http
$scheme = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_SCHEME);
$host = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST);
// do not encode the first '/' or the last '/'
$encodedPath = strtolower(urlencode(substr(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH), 1, -1)));

$encodedUrl = $scheme . "://" . $host . "/" . $encodedPath . "/";
```

[DEMO](http://3v4l.org/ck5Sv)